# Radial Limits of Singular Inner Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Given a positive singular measure $\mu$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, we define a singular inner function by

$$S(z)=\exp\left(-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\,d\mu(\theta)\right).$$

It is stated in many different sources that the radial limits $\lim_{r\rightarrow1^{-}}S(re^{2\pi it})$ equal 0 for $\mu$-a.e. $t\in\overline{\text{supp}}(\mu)$. None of them give a proof, and most of them say it is "easy to see." I personally have not been able to figure it out. Can anyone either give me a proof or direct me to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a positive singular measure on $[0,2\pi)$ then $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\mu((x-h,x+h))}{2h}=+\infty$$for $\mu$-almost every $t$. That much I know is in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis*, for example.

It follows that if $\mu$ is a singular measure on the circle then $$\lim_{r\to1}P[\mu](re^{it})=+\infty$$for $\mu$-almost every $t$, where $P[\mu]$ is the Poisson integral (as in Rudin). This is just because the Poisson kernel $P(r,t)$ satisfies $$P(1-\delta,t)\ge \frac c{\delta}\chi_{(-\delta,\delta)}.$$

If you note that $|e^{x+iy}|=e^x$ you're done if you just show that the real part of the integral in the exponent is $P[\mu]$; look at the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $\mu$-a.e. $x\in \text {supp} (\mu),$

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{(x-r,x+r)}d\mu = \infty.$$

Show this implies that $P_r(\mu)(x) \to \infty,$ where $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel. Now what is the relationship between $|S(re^{ix})|$ and $P_r(\mu)(x)?$